# Recounting tags in one query

Tags: mysql, tags

I have two tables: articles and tags.

```
ARTICLES
id
tags
content

TAGS
tag
amount
```

I need to recount the amount of all tags in TAGS table. This should not be difficult because I use FULLTEXT index in ARTICLES table - it is possible to search using

```
MATCH(tags) AGAINST ('+tag' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So it is similar to Stack Overflow database scheme.

I tried something like this, but obviously it is not working:

```
UPDATE tags 
SET tags.amount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles 
                      WHERE MATCH(articles.tags) 
                      AGAINST (CONCAT('+',tags.tag) IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? You get an error? If so what?

Comment: "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST" - problem with CONCAT

Comment: How are you storing multiple tags in a single column?

Comment: Tags are separated by space. Fulltext is working fine but I have to somehow add + before tag name

Answer (score 0):

Always read the manual when you get an error message, it's helpful most quickly:

> AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a literal string, not a variable or a column name.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

So what you try to achieve is done wrong. Use a literal string instead of a function (`CONCAT`) and a column name.

A related question is: [MySQL Match issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9295226/367456)