# MySQL Error 1210 : Incorrect arguments to AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of updating a website that was created a previous admin. Most of it is outdated php code however there is too much to change so I am working with what I have.

I am trying to run a search query as follows;

```
$term = trim($_REQUEST['term']);
$searchterm = mysql_real_escape_string($term, $link); //link to db

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
FROM vw_ft_search WHERE 
MATCH (party_name) 
AGAINST ('+$searchterm' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

This always throws the error below;

> MySQL Error 1210 : Incorrect arguments to AGAINST

I have read the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295226/mysql-match-issue) which advises using a literal string (which I think I am?). When I echo out the `$searchterm` it shows the correct search term ('Charles' in this case.)

I have also tried to run the query with a manual string entered as follows, however same result;

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
FROM vw_ft_search WHERE 
MATCH (party_name) 
AGAINST ('%Charles%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Is it something to do with the query, view, variable?

Any direction is appreciated. Quite new to php/mysql.

Comment: What happen if you remove the `%` sign?

Comment: Wildcard to use with `LIKE`, for full text search it should be asterisk. I didn't even use wildcards to do a full text search with a single word.

Comment: And for mysql fulltext search you can not put wildcard before the left most character.

Comment: No, I mean the '%'. Something like '+Charles' or '+Charles*' not '+*Charles'.

Comment: Example of query with `LIKE` . `SELECT * FROM vw_ft_search WHERE party_name LIKE %Charles%`

Comment: Are you misunderstanding something. I was giving an example not an answer. What I meant was, to use `MATCH` and `AGAINST` the wildcard should be `*` not `%`. And there are some set of rules for `FULLTEXT`  search in MYSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$term = trim($_REQUEST['term']);
$searchterm = mysql_real_escape_string($term, $link); //link to db
```

Add `*`, if you also want to match against `Charlesk`, `Charlesd`, etc.

```
$searchterm = $searchterm.'*';
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
FROM vw_ft_search WHERE 
MATCH (party_name) 
AGAINST ('$searchterm' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

And also beware of the stopwords which can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). Matching against stopwords will return nothing.

Comment: That is not setting variable again. That was concatenating the wild card. I tested this, the only difference with yours is that I didnt use `mysql_real_escape_string` because I used prepared statement. I guess somewhere else in your code then.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help! I have simply changed my query now to a much simpler one. Similar to your `SELECT * FROM vw_ft_search WHERE party_name LIKE %Charles%` suggestion. Answer accepted.